# Is it possible to run Ubuntu on a Nexus 7?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

Is it possible to run Ubuntu 12.04 or 12.10 on a Google Nexus Tablet? Would it be able to run Unity and/or Gnome Shell? or would it have to run a lighter desktop environment?

Answer (score 12):

Here is how you do it! Fresh off the press:

- https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Nexus7/Installation

and here's a guide for reporting bugs:

- http://chrismwayne.com/?p=94

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ considering how the documentation for this is likely to keep changing over the next cycle, whatever is here will likely get outdated quickly.

Answer (score 6):

It definitely is possible - [here is a video taken by a Canonical employee](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2tGHfmM-TU) showing Ubuntu (what appears to be either 12.04 or 12.10) running on a Nexus7. We just don't know how they did it. The accompanying [blog post is here](http://victorpalau.net/2012/10/19/nexus-7-raring-to-go-to-copenhaguen/)

[Mark Shuttleworths blog post](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1195) announcing the name for Ubuntu 13.04 (Raring Ringtail) has the following note at the bottom:

> **So bring along a Nexus 7** if you’re coming to Copenhagen, because it makes a rumpty reference for our rootin’ tootin’ radionic razoring. The raving Rick and his merry (wo)men will lead us to a much leaner, sharper, more mobile world. We’ll make something… wonderful, and call it the Raring Ringtail. See you there soon.

So in short, it's been done. How to do it though... well, we don't know that.

Answer (score 4):

That's an interesting question :)

A quick google search finds [a thread on xda-developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1804130):

> Yea, both devices would run Ubuntu fine, but you would need a
>   mouse/keyboard for any sort of functionality.

I would imagine making Ubuntu to run on a tablet would be an exciting weekend project but don't expect the end result to be really useful.

Here's even an article titled [How to Install Ubuntu on Android](http://androlinux.com/android-ubuntu-development/how-to-install-ubuntu-on-android/), which should provide general directions.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Actually, it's pretty easy if you are already rooted. You can find instructions on [LinuxOnAndroid](http://linuxonandroid.org/)'s website.

Once you've got your Nexus rooted download the [Complete Linux Installer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zpwebsites.linuxonandroid) application.

I installed Lubuntu on my aging Samsung Captivate (AT&T's version of the first-generation Galaxy S), and it does work. I installed TeXlive on it and was able to edit and compile a couple of tex files, and preview them using evince or epdfview. It's pretty amazing actually.

Of course, for me it was just a fun project to try out, but I guess that, with a keyboard, a Nexus 7 could actually be useful as a Linux tablet. You do need enough storage capacity of course, because you are installing a desktop Linux distro after all.